# How to apply LUT (from .png) to an image? (Swift + Xcode)

Tags: swift, image, colors, lookup-tables, ciimage

I am trying to apply a LUT to an image by pressing a button.
Because, I am new to programming I mostly copied code and tried to modify it for my own project. I get no error messages, but when I try to press the button there is no effect on the image.

When I change the filter-name to sth. different than: "CIColorCube", the app even crashes with the error message: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

[My LUT Image that I am using. (size: 512x512)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWdP8.png)

```
func colorCubeFilterFromLUT(imageName : String) -> CIFilter? {

    let size = 512

    let lutImage    = UIImage(named: "LUT.png")!.cgImage
    let lutWidth    = lutImage!.width
    let lutHeight   = lutImage!.height
    let rowCount    = lutHeight / size
    let columnCount = lutWidth / size

    if ((lutWidth % size != 0) || (lutHeight % size != 0) || (rowCount * columnCount != size)) {
        NSLog("Invalid colorLUT %@", "LUT.png");
        return nil
    }

    let bitmap  = getBytesFromImage(image: UIImage(named: "LUT.png"))!
    let floatSize = MemoryLayout<Float>.size

    let cubeData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: size * size * size * 4 * floatSize)
    var z = 0
    var bitmapOffset = 0

    for _ in 0 ..< rowCount {
        for y in 0 ..< size {
            let tmp = z
            for _ in 0 ..< columnCount {
                for x in 0 ..< size {

                    let alpha   = Float(bitmap[bitmapOffset]) / 255.0
                    let red     = Float(bitmap[bitmapOffset+1]) / 255.0
                    let green   = Float(bitmap[bitmapOffset+2]) / 255.0
                    let blue    = Float(bitmap[bitmapOffset+3]) / 255.0

                    let dataOffset = (z * size * size + y * size + x) * 4

                    cubeData[dataOffset + 3] = alpha
                    cubeData[dataOffset + 2] = red
                    cubeData[dataOffset + 1] = green
                    cubeData[dataOffset + 0] = blue
                    bitmapOffset += 4
                }
                z += 1
            }
            z = tmp
        }
        z += columnCount
    }

    let colorCubeData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: cubeData, length: size * size * size * 4 * floatSize, freeWhenDone: true)

    // create CIColorCube Filter
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube")
    filter?.setValue(colorCubeData, forKey: "inputCubeData")
    filter?.setValue(size, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")

    return filter
}


func getBytesFromImage(image:UIImage?) -> [UInt8]?
{
    var pixelValues: [UInt8]?
    if let imageRef = image?.cgImage {
        let width = Int(imageRef.width)
        let height = Int(imageRef.height)
        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4
        let totalBytes = height * bytesPerRow

        let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var intensities = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)

        let contextRef = CGContext(data: &intensities, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
        contextRef?.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))

        pixelValues = intensities
    }
    return pixelValues!
}

@IBAction func filterRetro(_ sender: Any) {
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: photo.image!)

    let filteredImage = inputImage?.applyingFilter("CIColorCube")

    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, from: (filteredImage?.extent)!)

    photo.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderedImage!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in your IBAction func filterRetro

```
 if let photoImage = photo.image  {
                let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImage)
                let filteredImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIColorCube")
                let filteredExtent = filteredImage.extent

                /* hoping this will return a CGImage */
                let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, from: filteredExtent)
                photo.image =  UIImage(cgImage: renderedImage)
            }
```

The issue with optional wrapping inside the button press action is solved. But not with whole code. Let me know whether this works or not.

[edit]

inputImage.applyingFilter("name") method is calling the CIFilter.init(name). For which doc says,

> The name of the filter. You must make sure the name is spelled
>   correctly, otherwise your app will run but not produce any output
>   images. For that reason, you should check for the existence of the
>   filter after calling this method.

I would suggest using a separate variable to create the filter and if the filter exists then only apply to the image.

```
let filter = CIFilter("CIColorCube")
if filter {
   let filteredImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIColorCube")
}
```

try this.

thanks,
J

Comment: Can you give more details on the crash?
1. Is crashing happens for the same reason? Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping.
2. Is crashing happening when you click on the Button?

Comment: Crashing only happens when I change the name of the CIFilter. When I use "CIColorCube", nothing happens when I click the button and there is no error message. When I change the name to sth. different (e.g. "CIRetroFilter"), the app crashes with the error message: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". This only happens when I press the button. Thank you for your help!